# Google App Engine removing carriage return from PNG file signature, corrupting the image

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm deploying a simple flask app to GAE using `gcloud app deploy` command on Windows. `app.yaml` file includes a route for the index, one for serving static files and delegates the rest to the flask app:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: html/index.html
    upload: html/index.html
  - url: /static
    static_dir: assets/static
  - url: /api/.*
    script: auto
```

All non-png assets, index page and api calls work fine. However png files are corrupted.

I downloaded the corrupt png and did a byte-wise diff with its original to find out that the GAE-served version is missing the `\r` that's supposed to follow `PNG` in the png file signature ([details on PNG file signature](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html))

I tried deploying the app from Ubuntu as well, thinking it might be Windows-specific, but it didn't make any difference. Issue is reproducible with any png file I tried using.

Is there a way to tell GAE not to mess with carriage returns in certain files?

Note: It's not a cache issue, since I'm able deploy new pngs (including directly from Ubuntu) which all have the same issue. It's also been over 12 hours since I first deployed from Ubuntu and the original pngs are still broken as well

Comment: Are the PNG files served as static files or via flask? If via flask - can you show the code?

Comment: @DanCornilescu they're served as static files by the app engine, using route handlers in the `app.yaml` file

Comment: When you tried deploying using Ubuntu instead of Windows, did you wait long enough for the static file cache to expire? (expiration is 10 min) Many people use PNG on GAE so GAE works fine and it is something about your deployment.

Comment: @gaefan It's been over 12 hours since I deployed from ubuntu and the issue still stands.